# Getting separate axis labels on R plotly subplots

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

When using the R `plotly` package version 4.5.6 I haven't been able to figure out how to get axis labels to appear when combining multiple plots using `subplot`.  Here is an example where no x-axis labels appear.

```
require(plotly)
a <- data.frame(x1=1:3,   y=30:32)
b <- data.frame(x2=11:13, y=31:33)

u <- plot_ly(a)
u <- add_lines(u, x=~x1, y=~y)
v <- plot_ly(b)
v <- add_lines(v, x=~x2, y=~y)
subplot(u, v, shareY=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get x-axis labels to show up with `subplot`, you can set `titleX = TRUE`.  The default is `titleX = shareX`, and in your example, `shareX = FALSE` (the default).

```
subplot(u, v, shareY = TRUE, titleX = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  A somewhat related question is that I really want to use a general character string for the axis labels.  I can add calls to `layout(..., xaxis=list(title=...))` for the individual plots before calling `subplot` with `titleX=TRUE` and it also works.  I just wonder if calling `layout` is the recommended approach.

Comment: @FrankHarrell using `layout` as you describe seems to be the approach in most examples I see.  You can also use layout after constructing the subplot. For instance:  `subplot(u, v, shareY = TRUE, titleX = TRUE) %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = "X1"), xaxis2 = list(title = "X2"))`.