# Adding color and bubble size legend in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, legend

Probably an easy one.

I have an xy dataset I'd like to plot using `R`'s `plotly`. Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10,1,10),group=c(rep("A",9),"B"),group.size=as.integer(runif(10,1,10)))
```

I'd like to color the data by `df$group` and have the size of the points follow `df$group.size` (i.e., a bubble plot). In addition, I'd like to have both legends added.

This is my naive attempt:

```
require(plotly)  
require(dplyr)  

    main.plot <-
 plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",color=~df$group,x=~df$x,y=~df$y,size=~df$group.size,marker=list(sizeref=0.1,sizemode="area",opacity=0.5),data=df,showlegend=T) %>%
     layout(title="Title",xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F))
```

which comes out as:
[image]

and unfortunately messes up the legend, at least how I want it to be: a point for each group having the same size but different colors.

Then to add a legend for the `group.size` I followed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvLSu.png), also helped by aocall's answer:

```
legend.plot <- plot_ly() %>% add_markers(x = 1, y = unique(df$group.size),
                                size = unique(df$group.size),
                                showlegend = T, 
                                marker = list(sizeref=0.1,sizemode="area")) %>%
   layout(title="TITLE",xaxis = list(zeroline=F,showline=F,showticklabels=F,showgrid=F),
          yaxis=list(showgrid=F))
```

which comes out as:
[image]

Here my problem is that the legend is including values that do not exist in my data.

then I combine them using `subplot`:

```
subplot(legend.plot, main.plot, widths = c(0.1, 0.9))
```

I get this:
[image]

where the legend title is eliminated

So I'd be helpful for some help.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383244/size-legend-for-plotly-bubble-map-chart

Comment: Tried it and updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updated request:

Note the changes in `legend.plot` (mapping values to a sequence of integers, then manually changing the axis tick text), and the use of annotations to get a legend title. As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285729/how-to-give-subtitles-for-subplot-in-plot-ly-using-r), only one title may be used, regardless of how many subplots are used.

The circle on the plot legend seems to correspond to the minimum point size of each trace. Thus, I've added a point at (12, 12), and restricted the range of the axes to ensure it isn't shown.

`titleX` and `titleY` control the display of axis labels, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324934/getting-separate-axis-labels-on-r-plotly-subplots#41325577).

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10,1,10),group=c(rep("A",9),"B"),group.size=as.integer(runif(10,1,10)))
require(plotly)  
require(dplyr)  


## Take unique values before adding dummy value
unique_vals <- unique(df$group.size)
df <- rbind(c(12, 12, "B", 1), df)
df[c(1, 2, 4)] <- lapply(df[c(1, 2, 4)], as.numeric)


main.plot <-
  plot_ly(type='scatter',
    mode="markers",
    color=~df$group,
    x=~df$x,
    y=~df$y,
    size=~df$group.size,
    marker=list(
        sizeref=0.1,
        sizemode="area",
        opacity=0.5),
        data=df,
        showlegend=T) %>%
  layout(title="Title",
    xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F, range=c(0, 11)),
    yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F, range=c(0, 11)))

legend.plot <- plot_ly() %>% 
    add_markers(x = 1, 
    y = seq_len(length(unique_vals)),
    size = sort(unique_vals),
    showlegend = F, 
    marker = list(sizeref=0.1,sizemode="area")) %>%
    layout(
        annotations = list(
            list(x = 0.2, 
                y = 1, 
                text = "LEGEND TITLE", 
                showarrow = F, 
                xref='paper', 
                yref='paper')),
         xaxis = list(
            zeroline=F,
            showline=F,
            showticklabels=F,
            showgrid=F),
         yaxis=list(
            showgrid=F,
            tickmode = "array",
            tickvals = seq_len(length(unique_vals)),
            ticktext = sort(unique_vals)))


subplot(legend.plot, main.plot, widths = c(0.1, 0.9), 
    titleX=TRUE, titleY=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks again. The legend of main.plot still has blue circle around it. Did you notice that?

Comment: Another issue is that the legend eliminates the axes labels

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are only passing in the unique values to the legend. If you pass in all possible values (ie, `seq(min(x), max(x), by=1)`, or in this case `seq_len(max(x))`) the legend will show the full range.

Secondly, `sizeref` and `sizemode` in the `marker` argument alter the way that point size is calculated. The following example should produce a more consistent plot:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10,1,10),group=c(rep("A",9),"B"),group.size=as.integer(runif(10,1,10)))

require(plotly)  
require(dplyr)  

a <- plot_ly(type='scatter',mode="markers",
    color=~df$group,
    x=~df$x,
    y=~df$y,
    size=df$group.size,
    marker = list(sizeref=0.1, sizemode="area"),
    data=df,
    showlegend=F) %>%
    layout(title="Title",
        xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F),
        yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F))

b <- plot_ly() %>% add_markers(x = 1, y = seq_len(max(df$group.size)),
    size = seq_len(max(df$group.size)), 
    showlegend = F, 
    marker = list(sizeref=0.1, sizemode="area")) %>%
    layout(
        xaxis = list(zeroline=F,showline=F,showticklabels=F,showgrid=F),
        yaxis=list(showgrid=F))


subplot(b, a, widths = c(0.1, 0.9))
```

Comment: Thanks @aocall. The reason I was passing the unique values is that I don't think that circle areas that do not exist in my data should be represented in the legend - I mean why would a legend describe features that are not in the data. But seems like plotly will show the values of these regardless. Right?

Comment: Sorrry, I misunderstood. 

I guess it's a taste thing, but I would show the full range of sizes, not just the ones which occur. Also, if you want to alter the values shown on the y axis of the legend (only show the unique values) then you'll need to do a bit more customisation of that subplot.

Comment: It's ok. Your answer was helpful. I edited the question integrating your code since there are a few more items I need help with.