# Plot multiple legends in R-plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have 5 continuous variables that I'd like to graph together in R plotly.

I wrote the following code and got the plot to run as expected, but I cannot figure out how to deal with the legends. As is, the color legend appears, but the size legend does not.

I would like to plot both legends and control their locations within the plot. Suggestions from a similar post [Adding color and bubble size legend in R plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036672/adding-color-and-bubble-size-legend-in-r-plotly) do not solve the problem.

Here's the code and sample data:

```
x<-sample(30)
y<-sample(30)
z<-sample(30)
c<-sample(30)
s<-sample(30)

fig <- plot_ly (x = x, y = y, z = z, color = c, 
                colors = c("#440154FF", "#1F968BFF", "#FDE725FF"), size = s,
                marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter'), sizes = c(1, 30))

fig <- fig %>% add_markers()

fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list (title = 'X'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'Y'),
                      zaxis = list(title = 'Z'),
                      annotations = list(x = 1.05, y =1.02,
                                         text = 'Gradient title',
                                         xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper',
                                         showarrow=FALSE, showlegend=TRUE)))

fig
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I have an answer. Initially, I tried to make the legend a subplot, but the legend from the 3D markers is offset from the plot-as-a-legend of bubble sizes. To fix that issue, I created an image of the bubbles and added it to the original plot as an image.

Using the information from `fig` in your original code, I created another figure (the bubbles and sizes).

```
figB <- plot_ly(x = 1, y = seq(30, 5, by = -5), 
                size = seq(30, 5, by = -5),
                sizes = c(1, 30),
                type = "scatter",
                mode = "markers",
                color = seq(30, 5, by = -5),
                colors = c("#440154FF", "#1F968BFF", "#FDE725FF"), 
                marker = list(sizeref = 0.1, 
                              sizemode = "area"),
                height = 275, width = 100) %>%

  layout(
    xaxis = list(zeroline = F, showline = F, showticklabels = F, showgrid = F),
    yaxis = list(showgrid = F, side = "right")) %>% # numbers on right (as fig legend)
   hide_colorbar()
figB
```

[image]

I used three different libraries for this next part: `htmlwidgets`, `webshot`, and `magick`.

```
# create temp files
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")  # plotly to html
tmp2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")  # html to png

# create html
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(figB, tmp, background = "transparent")
# create png
webshot::webshot(tmp, tmp2, zoom = 2, vwidth = 150, vheight = 275) # to get great res

# make the png an object
itsBack <- magick::image_read(tmp2)

# check the amount of white space
magick::image_border(itsBack, "gray") # not too much white space; good res

unlink(tmp) # remove tempfile connection
unlink(tmp2)
```

For this last step, I copied the code from your original figure. The image needs to be added to `layout`. I removed code that didn't impact the figure, as well.

```
# set up placement of image below the initial legend
imgr = list(
  source = raster2uri(as.raster(itsBack)),
  xref = "paper",
  yref = "paper",
  y = .5,   # paper domain is 0 to 1, this puts the top in the middle
  x = .95,  # almost all the way right
  sizex = .45,  # scale image down (0-1)
  sizey = .45,  # scale image down (0-1)
  opacity = 1,
  layer = "above")

# Rebuild fig without the initial legend - then add imgr to the legend
fig <- plot_ly (x = x, y = y, z = z, color = c, 
                colors = c("#440154FF", "#1F968BFF", "#FDE725FF"), 
                size = s,
                marker = list(symbol = 'circle', 
                              sizemode = 'diameter'), 
                sizes = c(1, 30))

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'X'),
               yaxis = list(title = 'Y'),
               zaxis = list(title = 'Z')),
  images = imgr) # adding bubbles here

fig
```

Depending on what you're doing with the graph, the placement and scaling may need to be adjusted. While `plotly` objects scale dynamically, the `png` won't be nearly as dynamic-friendly. The image is scaled down to 45% of its original size, so you have a lot of room to grow, but you may have to adjust those parameters (`sizex` and `sizey`). If you rescale your viewer window, you may also need to refresh the view. (Use the refresh icon in the Viewer pane.)

[image]