# Add a second legend for size in a plot except for the one for the color gradient

Tags: r, plotly

I have the data below

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(plotly)

    topic_stats2<-structure(list(topicLabel = c("AI and ChatGPT in Education and Academic Research", 
    "AI in Material Science and Molecular Discovery", "AI in Peer Review and Scientific Journals", 
    "Advancements in Code Generation and Software Engineering", "Advancements in Dialogue Systems and Conversational AI", 
    "Advancements in Information Retrieval and Query Ranking", "Advancements in Speech Recognition and Audio Processing", 
    "Adversarial Attacks and Safety in Large Language Models", "Autonomous Driving and AI", 
    "Autonomous Language Agents and Game Theory"), x_of_centroid = c(0.91871597286307, 
    -2.49566595157895, 0.20997164828, -1.1914680081768, -0.129559583644202, 
    -1.96149233684211, 2.79425485970696, -2.54531605677419, 4.21323109, 
    1.85972925123153), y_of_centroid = c(5.49145608215768, 1.64866348, 
    5.29254033, 13.6509021731123, 8.19892662404372, 8.91596759774436, 
    11.2457938992674, 12.2423231612903, 7.735923416, 8.1711380955665
    ), number_papers = c(241L, 95L, 50L, 543L, 183L, 133L, 273L, 
    155L, 50L, 203L), avg_influentialCitationCount = c(0.161825726141079, 
    0.231578947368421, 0.14, 0.456721915285451, 1.62295081967213, 
    0.255639097744361, 0.373626373626374, 0.909677419354839, 0.32, 
    0.655172413793103), avg_referenceCount = c(34.551867219917, 48.7263157894737, 
    22.74, 47.5451197053407, 41.879781420765, 44.5187969924812, 37.4395604395604, 
    49.0903225806452, 50.18, 45.0886699507389), total_citationCount = c(750L, 
    380L, 94L, 2679L, 2245L, 416L, 973L, 1273L, 141L, 1506L), total_influentialCitationCount = c(39L, 
    22L, 7L, 248L, 297L, 34L, 102L, 141L, 16L, 133L), avg_citationCount = c(3.11203319502075, 
    4, 1.88, 4.93370165745856, 12.2677595628415, 3.12781954887218, 
    3.56410256410256, 8.21290322580645, 2.82, 7.41871921182266), 
        proportion_papers_with_0_citations = c(0.597510373443983, 
        0.473684210526316, 0.72, 0.486187845303867, 0.546448087431694, 
        0.496240601503759, 0.556776556776557, 0.367741935483871, 
        0.42, 0.369458128078818), proportion_papers_with_0_influential_citations = c(0.900414937759336, 
        0.884210526315789, 0.9, 0.848987108655617, 0.85792349726776, 
        0.879699248120301, 0.879120879120879, 0.696774193548387, 
        0.8, 0.798029556650246), HHI = c(0.00158799209187012, 0.00216655188246097, 
        0.00688772629756483, 0.000580904637325075, 0.00111496611860673, 
        0.00215073695918234, 0.00106218461882422, 0.00145941854646373, 
        0.00424016087331227, 0.000935096539016183), scaled_HHI = c(1.11159446430908, 
        1.51658631772268, 4.82140840829538, 0.406633246127553, 0.780476283024711, 
        1.50551587142764, 0.743529233176955, 1.02159298252461, 2.96811261131859, 
        0.654567577311328), scaled_num_papers = c(2.41, 0.95, 0.5, 
        5.43, 1.83, 1.33, 2.73, 1.55, 0.5, 2.03), scaled_avg_influentialCitationCount = c(0.485477178423237, 
        0.694736842105263, 0.42, 1.37016574585635, 4.86885245901639, 
        0.766917293233083, 1.12087912087912, 2.72903225806452, 0.96, 
        1.96551724137931), scaled_total_influentialCitationCount = c(0.39, 
        0.22, 0.07, 2.48, 2.97, 0.34, 1.02, 1.41, 0.16, 1.33), scaled_avg_citationCount = c(0.933609958506224, 
        1.2, 0.564, 1.48011049723757, 3.68032786885246, 0.938345864661654, 
        1.06923076923077, 2.46387096774194, 0.846, 2.2256157635468
        ), scaled_total_citationCount = c(0.5625, 0.285, 0.0705, 
        2.00925, 1.68375, 0.312, 0.72975, 0.95475, 0.10575, 1.1295
        ), scaled_avg_referenceCount = c(1.72759336099585, 2.43631578947368, 
        1.137, 2.37725598526704, 2.09398907103825, 2.22593984962406, 
        1.87197802197802, 2.45451612903226, 2.509, 2.25443349753695
        ), scaled_proportion_papers_with_0_citations = c(2.39004149377593, 
        1.89473684210526, 2.88, 1.94475138121547, 2.18579234972678, 
        1.98496240601504, 2.22710622710623, 1.47096774193548, 1.68, 
        1.47783251231527), scaled_proportion_papers_with_0_influential_citations = c(1.80082987551867, 
        1.76842105263158, 1.8, 1.69797421731123, 1.71584699453552, 
        1.7593984962406, 1.75824175824176, 1.39354838709677, 1.6, 
        1.59605911330049)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))

and I want to create a plot with a legend for the color and a legend for the size not only for the color


 d<-(max(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount)-min(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount))/5
library(plotly)
library(magick)
figB <- plot_ly(x = min(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), y = seq(max(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), min(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), by = -d), 
                size = seq(max(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), min(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), by = -d),
                sizes = c(min(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), max(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount)),
                type = "scatter",
                mode = "markers",
                color = seq(max(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), min(topic_stats2$avg_referenceCount), by = -d),
                colors = c("lightcoral", "darkred"),
                marker = list(sizeref = 0.1, 
                              sizemode = "area"),
                height = 275, width = 100) %>%
  
  layout(
    xaxis = list(zeroline = F, showline = F, showticklabels = F, showgrid = F),
    yaxis = list(showgrid = F, side = "right")) %>% # numbers on right (as fig legend)
  hide_colorbar()
figB


# create temp files
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")  # plotly to html
tmp2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")  # html to png

# create html
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(figB, tmp, background = "transparent")
# create png
webshot::webshot(tmp, tmp2, zoom = 2, vwidth = 150, vheight = 275) # to get great res

# make the png an object
itsBack <- magick::image_read(tmp2)

# check the amount of white space
magick::image_border(itsBack, "gray") # not too much white space; good res

unlink(tmp) # remove tempfile connection
unlink(tmp2)




# set up placement of image below the initial legend
imgr = list(
  source = raster2uri(as.raster(itsBack)),
  xref = "paper",
  yref = "paper",
  y = .5,   # paper domain is 0 to 1, this puts the top in the middle
  x = .95,  # almost all the way right
  sizex = .45,  # scale image down (0-1)
  sizey = .45,  # scale image down (0-1)
  opacity = 1,
  layer = "above")


plot <- plot_ly(data = topic_stats2, x = ~number_papers, y = ~total_citationCount, 
                type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
                marker = list(size = ~scaled_avg_referenceCount, sizemode = 'diameter', sizeref = 0.1,
                              color = ~HHI,
                              colorscale = c("lightcoral", "darkred"),  # Custom red color range
                              showscale = TRUE),  # Show color scale legend
                hoverinfo = 'text',
                text = ~paste(
                  '<b>Topic:</b>', topicLabel,
                  '<br><b>HHI:</b>', HHI,
                  '<br><b>Num Papers:</b>', number_papers,
                  '<br><b>Avg Influential Citations:</b>', avg_influentialCitationCount,
                  '<br><b>Total Influential Citations:</b>', total_influentialCitationCount,
                  '<br><b>Avg Citations:</b>', avg_citationCount,
                  '<br><b>Total Citations:</b>', total_citationCount,
                  '<br><b>Avg Reference Count:</b>', avg_referenceCount,
                  '<br><b>Proportion Papers with 0 Citations:</b>', proportion_papers_with_0_citations,
                  '<br><b>Proportion Papers with 0 Influential Citations:</b>', proportion_papers_with_0_influential_citations
                ))
# Customize layout
plot <- plot %>% layout(title = 'X Variable vs Y Variable',
                        xaxis = list(title = 'Average 2D Vector Embedding X Location of Papers'),
                        yaxis = list(title = 'Average 2D Vector Embedding Y Location of Papers'),
                        images = imgr)
# Render the plot
plot
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a feature not supported by plotly. See the discussion on GH: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5099

Comment: It's not a native Plotly element, but you can make it look like it is. See if [this is what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011571/plot-multiple-legends-in-r-plotly). There are other methods to make this happen, as well. Let me know if you're looking for something like this.

Comment: very helpful indeed this is what im trying to do

Comment: I have managed to put the second lagened but how can I put one below the other or possibly one next to the other but with the same height?check my edit